# Moving lines to separate files all at once

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, grep

I have many files and I want to export certain lines to new files while maintaining the input files as they are. For example, I want all lines beginning with a to be sent to a new file, let's call that a.txt, and then I want all other lines to be sent to a separate file, bcd.txt.

```
a.......

b.......

c.......

a.......

d.......
```

Currently, I'm using `grep '^a' infile.txt > a.txt` to do the first part and then I duplicated the input file and used `sed -i 's/^a.*$//g` to just delete the a lines starting with a. Is there a way I can do both tasks, while maintaining the original input file and not duplicating it?

Comment: `sed -n -e 's/^a/&/w a.txt' -e t -e p < infile.txt > bcd.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all the line that starts with an `a`:

```
grep '^a' infile.txt >a.txt
```

To get all the lines that does not start with an 'a':

```
grep '^[^a]' infile >bcd.txt   # or grep -v '^a' infile.txt >bcd.txt
```

The expression `[^...]` means "any character not in this set of characters" and the set contains a single `a`.

Combined action, using `awk`:

```
awk '/^a/ { print >"a.txt"; next } { print >"bcd.txt" }' infile.txt
```

The `awk` program triggers the first block for any line starting with an `a` and the second block for all other lines (not the `a` lines, due to the `next` statement in the first block).  The `print >filename` statement will print the current line to the given file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the non-`a` lines to be sent to `bcd.txt`, simply invert the `grep`:

```
grep    '^a' infile.txt > a.txt
grep -v '^a' infile.txt > bcd.txt
```

Another option, using only one command, would be awk:

```
awk '/^a/ { print > "a.txt" } ! /^a/ { print > "bcd.txt" }' < input
```

Rearranged a bit, this looks like:

```
awk '
    /^a/ { print > "a.txt" } 
  ! /^a/ { print > "bcd.txt" }' 
  < input
```

... where lines that start with `a` enter the first block and are written (appended) to `a.txt`, while lines that do *not* start with `a` go into the second block and are written (appended) to `bcd.txt`.